# Histogram generation, Differentiate between dark red and light red color

Tags: java

I have an existing java code on which i have to make some changes. Its an image processing application. The program extracts number of pixels for colors red, orange and green from a line image. I have this following code. What i understand is that a histogram is generated and pixel values for red, orange and green color is calculated.

```
// Color space transform and histogram generation


    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    WritableRaster rasterMask = mask.getRaster();

    int[] pixel = new int[3];
    int[] pixelMask = new int[3];

    float[] hsv = new float[3];

    int[] quant = new int[3];

    int[][][] histogram = new int[30][8][8];

    for (int x = 0; x < raster.getWidth(); x++) { 
        for (int y = 0; y < raster.getHeight(); y++) {
            rasterMask.getPixel(x, y, pixelMask);

            if(pixelMask[0] != 0 && pixelMask[1] != 0 && pixelMask[2] != 0)      {
                raster.getPixel(x, y, pixel);
                Color.RGBtoHSB(pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2], hsv);

                hsv[0] = hsv[0] * 360;

                quant[0] = (int)((float)hsv[0] / 12f);
                quant[1] = (int)((float)((float)hsv[1] / 0.125f));
                quant[2] = (int)((float)((float)hsv[2] / 0.125f));

                if(quant[0] == 30) { quant[0] = 29; }
                if(quant[1] == 8) { quant[1] = 7; }
                if(quant[2] == 8) { quant[2] = 7; }

                histogram[quant[0]][quant[1]][quant[2]]++;

            }
        }
    }

for(int i=4; i<8; i++) {
        for(int j=4; j<8; j++) {
            // red
            colorRed[2] += histogram[0][i][j];
            colorRed[2] += histogram[1][i][j];

            // orange
            colorOrange[1] += histogram[2][i][j];

            // green
            colorGreen[0] += histogram[7][i][j];
            colorGreen[0] += histogram[8][i][j];
            colorGreen[0] += histogram[9][i][j];
        }
    }
```

My part is to differentiate between dark red and light red colors. That is get the number of pixels in dark red and number of pixels in light red. I am clueless how to proceed. Can anyone please help. thanks

Comment: How are you defining "dark red" and "light red"?

Comment: Thank you for replying and your interest. I mean can i differentiate somewhere midway between high intensity and low intensity in color.

Comment: Exactly, you need to understand and decide how you are going to differentiate the two shades. Solve the actual problem first (what is dark vs light red?) before trying to solve the programming problem (how do I write a program to differentiate dark vs light red?). If you understand the first, it should help lead you to the second.

Comment: Sorry but I just thought if someone could help me to solve the problem or at least trigger some idea  which can further  lead me to understand the actual problem. I was stuck with no where to go and thought just getting a second opinion could help. Now i am scared to post a question here in stack overflow since i feel more demotivated and afraid for being put down again.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. Lots of questions get downvoted or criticized. Perhaps you might explain why you need to differentiate these colors. You could threshold brightness or just the value of the red component. Different methods might be better for different applications.

Comment: Color is made up of components, Red/Green/Blue, Hue/Saturation/Brightness, etc. So what range of RGB / HSB values give you dark red and what range gives you light red? You might have to open up a color picker to decide values (http://www.colorpicker.com/). Note light / dark is subjective to a point so the ranges you choose might be a little bit different than the ranges I would choose. Then in your program, check if your current pixel is in either the "dark red" range, "light red" range, or neither.

Comment: Thank you Will...When you mentioned brightness it triggered me that perhaps its not the color but the brightness of red. Brighter and darker. And as i was looking a midway between the two, solved the problem like this. Thank you for your kind words and help.                                  : if(j>5)
 red+= histogram[0][i][j];
else
// darkRed
 darkred += histogram[0][i][j];